# Getting the ID of selected table in HTML select

Tags: php, sql, html, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

Im making a online shop assignment for university with Bootstrap/PHP/PDO/SQL. So far, i've made a page which allows me to input a product category to the database, the table is called "tuoteryhma", which holds values "name" and "id". Now im making a page, which would add a product to "product"-table.

Im trying to accomplish this, via a basic HTML form, the top being a select class, which i have linked to the database "tuoteryhma" like so:

```
<?php
      try {

          $sqljr='SELECT * FROM tuoteryhma';
          $kyselyx=$tietokantajr->query($sqljr);

          while ($tietuejr = $kyselyx->fetch()) {
              print  '<option>' . $tietuejr['nimi'] . '</option>';          
          }

      } catch (PDOException $pdoexjr) {
          print "Tietokannan avaus epäonnistui." . $pdoexjr->getMessage();
      }
      ?>
```

And it works correctly. Now my problem is that i need to somehow get the id value of selected "tuoteryhma" table and add id to the "add product" part of the code. The ID of tuoteryhma is the foreign key of tuote table.

I've been trying to add codelines to the while loop you can see above, like:

```
 $id = $tietuejr['id']
```

And then placing the $id variable as the select value like so:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="tuoteryhmat" value="<?php $id ?>" id="tuoteryhmat">
```

And then using that in my other try-catch statement, which would (if it would work) add the new product to product table, like so:

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['tuoteryhmat'])) {
try {


      $nimijr = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'nimi',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $kuvausjr = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'kuvaus',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      $hintajr = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'hinta',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
      $idjr2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tuoteryhma_id');

          $kyselyjr2 = $tietokantajr->prepare("INSERT INTO
          tuote (nimi,kuvaus,hinta,tuoteryhma_id) VALUES  

    (:nimi,:kuvaus,:hinta,tuoteryhma_id:)");

          $kyselyjr2->bindValue(':nimi', $nimijr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $kyselyjr2->bindValue(':kuvaus', $kuvausjr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $kyselyjr2->bindValue(':hinta', $hintajr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $kyselyjr2->bindValue(':tuoteryhma_id', $idjr2, PDO::PARAM_STR);


          $kyselyjr2->execute();

          print "<p>VITTU</p>";

    print "<p>Tuote tallennettu onnistuneesti!</p>";
} catch (PDOException $pdoextuotejr) {
    print "Tuotteen tallennuksessa tapahtui virhe."
     . $pdoextuotejr->getMessage();
}


    }

?>
```

With no luck so far. 
Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

*edit sorry if i wasnt clear on some things, or left something imporant out of this. This is the .php page on its entirety: http://pastebin.com/JRwi8B2p

Comment: `value="<?php $id ?>"` you need to echo that. `value="<?php echo $id ?>"`

Comment: Oh, didnt notice that before. Changed it, but still doesnt work.

Comment: it's hard to say if you are using some form of POST method here. There isn't anything in your question that suggests `method="post"` or the use of a form, or jQuery's `$.post`. check for errors and check your console if you're using JS/Ajax.

Comment: I didnt want to paste the whole tuote.php, because it would be a really long post. But here would be the page in its entirety http://pastebin.com/JRwi8B2p Note that i open the db in top.php, which i use as the top of every page on the site.

Comment: It looks like you want the label of each option to be the `nimi` for that row but you want the value to be the `id` for that row. Is that correct?

Comment: well i think it's because the select box that you are creating has no value. you are creating <select value=""><option>text</option></select> which is wrong. you should assign the value attribute in the <option> tag example. <select id="id"><option value="1">text</option><option value="2">text2</option></select>

Comment: Oh crap you're right.

Comment: well it happens sometimes. :)

Comment: Still cant quite figure out how to actually get that value from db. What im trying right now is this, but it gives out an syntax error. print  '<option value= "$tietuejr['id']" >' . $tietuejr['nimi'] . '</option>';

Comment: echo "<option value='".$tietuejr['id']."' >".$tietuejr['nimi']."</option>";

Comment: You should post your solution as a proper answer below rather than editing the question. That will allow you to mark the answer as accepted, which is the community's indication that it has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ISSUE RESOLVED**
The problem was that the option fields i'm printing in while loop hold no value. I thought that the value itself would be held in the select class value="" which was not the case. So to resolve this, i had to change my while loop option printing, to take the value from the database.

```
   echo "<option value='".$tietuejr['id']."' >".$tietuejr['nimi']."</option>";
```

Thank you to **Codezilla** for pointing this out to me!

---